# Images appearing in search results (when they shouldn't)

Tags: 2013, search-results

Have two SP2013 on-prem site collections -- one where we explore and build tests and the other is for everyone in our company to use. In our "public" facing site search results we are trying to only show pages and documents that our users would be interested in. So we've gone through the list/library settings and marked them as No for "Allow items in this document library to appear in search results?"

For example the Style, Images, and Site Assets library. Those are not results our users will find valuable.

In our development site, this works great, but in our public site I'm still seeing some graphics from the images library. So for example we have a graphic for our department's logo. Someone might search on the name of our department and get a return of the logo. Not useful. The link returned is also strange.

```
<site>/PublishingImages/Forms/DispForm.aspx?ID=##
```

Not sure why it is to the display form.

I've checked that the library is not to be included and I've do a reindex (from the UI) for both the library and for the site, but that didn't fix it.

I added a new image to the library and strangely it doesn't appear in search results.

I've checked my result sources, search result webpart query builder, and search and offline availability settings and they are the same between the development and public sites. Not really sure where to go next.

**Edit**

Additional information. I just noticed that even the name of a folder in the image library is being included in the search results. So I think it must be indexing the list view pages? Why would it do that in one site but not in another?

And more importantly how do I tell it not to include urls like:

```
PublishingImages/Forms/Thumbnails.aspx
PublishingImages/Forms/Thumbnails.aspx?RootFolder=%2Fteams%2Ftop%2FPublishingImages%2Ffolder-namey&FolderCTID=0x012000A35920B88D683C4C8C4115EC9092245A&View=%7B3C17B5FA-1C6D-4A8C-A3FB-101B5E32A42E%7D
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to manage search exposure is to set permissions. Search is security trimmed. Although there may be "leaks" due to visibility via web parts.

As to why the images are being included... while the library is set to no crawl, and search is respecting that, search does crawl every page and every link in the site, just like how Google or Bing would crawl a web site. So, somewhere search has found a page with a web part that displays the content of that library. (which would explain why the display form is in the URL)

Comment: Permissions won't help in this case. Most of these files -- like the logo, or some of our css or code in Style need to be read by users, but aren't anything they are searching for. Some of the images aren't used at all and still show up, so the only page displaying them is the library itself. If there is a webpart displaying the content shouldn't it point to the page with the webpart?